# Installing python2.6 build dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am trying to install python2.6 buid dependencies using
sudo apt-get build-dep python2.6
But I get error E: Unable to find a source package for python2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the source repositories disabled in your */etc/apt/sources.list*. Find the line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu <version-name> main restricted multiverse
```

Duplicate it and change 'deb' to 'deb-src', like:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu <version-name> main restricted multiverse
```

Now run:

`sudo apt-get update`

You should then be able to install dependencies for Python by running:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get build-dep python-defaults` and this question belongs on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: could you please tell me where I can get python2.6 binaries for download